# Issue with CSS divs in Joomla 3 Template index.php file

Tags: php, html, css, joomla, indexing

We're having an issue with a Joomla site using Artisteer exported code (no choice), and we can't get our index.php working properly.

If you view the website at www.arctrades.com , you can see our issue. The content is in a div sitting at the bottom of the page, and won't float on the right hand side of the page where the content should go!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

/**
 * Template for Joomla! CMS, created with Artisteer.
 * See readme.txt for more details on how to use the template.
 */

require_once dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'functions.php';

// Create alias for $this object reference:
$document = $this;

// Shortcut for template base url:
$templateUrl = $document->baseurl . '/templates/' . $document->template;

Artx::load("Artx_Page");

// Initialize $view:
$view = $this->artx = new ArtxPage($this);

// Decorate component with Artisteer style:
$view->componentWrapper();

JHtml::_('behavior.framework', true);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="<?php echo $document->language; ?>">
<head>
    <jdoc:include type="head" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $document->baseurl; ?>/templates/system/css/system.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $document->baseurl; ?>/templates/system/css/general.css" />


    <!-- Created by Artisteer v4.2.0.60623 -->



    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="https://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->;
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $templateUrl; ?>/css/template.css" media="screen" />
    <!--[if lte IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $templateUrl; ?>/css/template.ie7.css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web&amp;subset=latin"; />


    <script>if ('undefined' != typeof jQuery) document._artxJQueryBackup = jQuery;</script>
    <script src="<?php echo $templateUrl; ?>/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>

    <script src="<?php echo $templateUrl; ?>/script.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo $templateUrl; ?>/modules.js"></script>
    <?php $view->includeInlineScripts() ?>
    <script>if (document._artxJQueryBackup) jQuery = document._artxJQueryBackup;</script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,700,900,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  </head>
<body>

<div id="art-main">

    <div class="art-sheet clearfix">
<?php echo $view->position('banner1', 'art-nostyle'); ?>

                                    <?php echo $view->positions(array('top1' => 15, 'top2' => 65, 'top3' => 20), 'art-nostyle'); ?>

<div class="art-content-layout">

<div class="art-layout-wrapper">



                    <div class="art-content-layout-row">


                        <?php if ($view->containsModules('left')) : ?>
                            <div class="art-layout-cell art-sidebar1">
<?php echo $view->position('left', 'art-block'); ?>





                        </div></div>
<?php endif; ?>
                                  <div class="art-layout-cell art-content">                         
<?php
echo $view->position('banner2', 'art-nostyle');
  if ($view->containsModules('breadcrumb'))
    echo artxPost($view->position('breadcrumb'));
  echo $view->positions(array('user1' => 50, 'user2' => 50), 'art-article');
  echo $view->position('banner3', 'art-nostyle');
  echo artxPost(array('content' => '<jdoc:include type="message" />', 'classes' => ' art-messages'));
  echo '<jdoc:include type="component" />';

  echo $view->position('banner4', 'art-nostyle');
  echo $view->positions(array('user4' => 50, 'user5' => 50), 'art-article');
  echo $view->position('banner5', 'art-nostyle');
?>



                        </div>
                        <?php if ($view->containsModules('right')) : ?>
<div class="art-layout-cell art-sidebar2">
<?php echo $view->position('right', 'art-block'); ?>


                        </div>
<?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
<?php echo $view->positions(array('bottom1' => 33, 'bottom2' => 33, 'bottom3' => 34), 'art-block'); ?>
<?php echo $view->position('banner6', 'art-nostyle'); ?>


    </div>
<footer class="art-footer">
  <div class="art-footer-inner">
<?php if ($view->containsModules('copyright')) : ?>
    <?php echo $view->position('copyright', 'art-nostyle'); ?>
<?php else: ?>
<p><a href="#">Link1</a> | <a href="#">Link2</a> | <a href="#">Link3</a></p>
<p>Copyright © 2013. All Rights Reserved.</p>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
</footer>

</div>


<?php echo $view->position('debug'); ?>
</body>
</html>​
```

Comment: The html markup is a little screwed. The left menu is wrapped in a div that is set to 100% and the content is in another wrapper which is set to 100% which is why the content is below. Shame you chose Artisteer to generate your template :/

Comment: Could you explain the code that is creating the 100% divs?

Trust me, using Artisteer is the company's choice, not mine. If I had hand coded the page these issues would not occur. 


If you help me resolve this issue I will PayPal you $10!

Comment: Could you please send me a copy of the template as it will be easier to fix it on my localhost than use the inspector on my browser. lodder15[at]hotmail.co.uk

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Sent an e-mail to you!